# Memory usage is not being measured when using %mprun from memory_profiler

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, memory-profiling

I am trying to measure the memory usage of the following function for factoring integers.

```
def trialDiv(n):
a = []
f = 2
while n != 1:
    if n % f == 0:
        a.append(f)
        n = n / f
    else:
        f = f + 1
return a
```

I am working in jupyter notebook and using memory_profiler. However, whenever I try and measure the memory usage of trialDiv by running

```
%mprun -f trialDiv trialDiv(n)
```

I get the following output.

## Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

```
 9     89.6 MiB     89.6 MiB   def trialDiv(n):
10     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = []
11     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       f = 2
12     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       while n != 1:
13     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           if n % f == 0:
14     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB               a.append(f)
15     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB               n = n / f
16                                     else:
17     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB               f = f + 1
18     89.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a
```

This is what is outputted regardless of the size of the integer passed into trialDiv. I feel like the function may not even be running at all or I am incorrectly using %mprun. Any advice would be appreciated.